# Can we add 'OR' operator along with if and else in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.6

In python, I'm doing a basic check if the object contains a key and getting data from it. But can we add or and check if obj1 does not contain data then check for obj2 and if not then return as None

I have tried as shown. Can I add or operator to this?

```
int(obj1.amt) if obj1.amt else None
```

Can we try to check if `obj1.amt` is None then check `obj1.new_amt` has value and return that, else return `None`

Comment: *if obj1.amt is None then check obj1.new_amt has value and return that, else return None* where do you need the `or` in it?

Comment: @DirtyBit I was thinking if we can use obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
v = obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt
int(v) if v else None
```

so it means that you can do this:

```
int(obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt) if obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt else None
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
int(obj1.amt) if obj1.amt else int(obj1.new_amt) if obj1.new_amt else None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int(obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt) if obj1.amt or obj1.new_amt else None
```